# Python RegEx to get words after a specific string

Tags: python, regex

having a string

> `string=
>   """"$deletedFields":["standardizedSkillUrn","standardizedSkill"],"entityUrn":"urn:li:fs_skill:(ACoAAAIv9SQBMzclPm3CZzL1QceTH5W0VrsdxbE,3)","name":"Finance","$type":"voyager.identity.profile.Skill"},{"$deletedFields":["standardizedSkillUrn","standardizedSkill"],"entityUrn":"urn:li:fs_skill:(ACoAAAIv9SQBMzclPm3CZzL1QceTH5W0VrsdxbE,22)","name":"Financial ["standardizedSkillUrn","standardizedSkill"],"entityUrn":"urn:li:fs_skill:(ACoAAAIv9SQBMzclPm3CZzL1QceTH5W0VrsdxbE,34)","name":"Due
>   Diligence","name":"Strategy""""`

What reguar expression can i use to retrieve values after "name": to get Due Dilligence, Financial, and Finance

i have tried

`match = re.compile(r'"name"\:(.\w+)')
 match.findall(string)`

but it returns

`['"Finance', '"Financial', '"Due', '"Financial', '"Strategy']`
The `Due Diligence` is split and i want both words as one.

Comment: How about: `r'"name":"([\w\s]+?)"'`

Comment: This looks like slightly broken JSON, the easiest way would be to go to the source of that data and fix it so that it generates *valid* JSON instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your whitespace is not detected by regex because `/w` only searches for non-special characters.

`"name"\:(.\w+\s*\w*)` accounts for any possible spaces with an extra word *(Will not work for three words, but will in your situation)*

`"name"\:(.\w+\s*\w*"?)` accounts for the quotations `"` at the end of each one but doesn't get Financial.
[Example](https://regex101.com/r/slwGyL/2)

Edit: Fixed second regex for "Financial

Answer (score 0):

I would use the non-hungry `.*?` expression with a trailing quote:

```
import re

string = """$deletedFields":["standardizedSkillUrn","standardizedSkill"],"entityUrn":"urn:li:fs_skill:(ACoAAAIv9SQBMzclPm3CZzL1QceTH5W0VrsdxbE,3)","name":"Finance","$type":"voyager.identity.profile.Skill"},{"$deletedFields":["standardizedSkillUrn","standardizedSkill"],"entityUrn":"urn:li:fs_skill:(ACoAAAIv9SQBMzclPm3CZzL1QceTH5W0VrsdxbE,22)","name":"Financial ["standardizedSkillUrn","standardizedSkill"],"entityUrn":"urn:li:fs_skill:(ACoAAAIv9SQBMzclPm3CZzL1QceTH5W0VrsdxbE,34)","name":"Due Diligence","name":"Strategy"""

# With the leading double quote
match = re.compile(r'"name"\:(".*?)["\[]')
a = match.findall(string)
print a

# Stripping out the leading double quote
match = re.compile(r'"name"\:"(.*?)["\[]')
b = match.findall(string)
print b
```

And the final output is:

```
['"Finance', '"Financial ', '"Due Diligence']
['Finance', 'Financial ', 'Due Diligence']
```